# SQL get all of the users last search

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I can easily get the users searches, but I would like to get all of the users LAST search. For example, the SQL code below will get this specific users last search.

```
select uid, itemDescription, date from SEARCH 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-30' 
        AND uid = "000-000-000-000-000"
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

If I try to edit this and remove the `uid = ""`, this wont work since it will limit to one search. If I remove the `LIMIT 1` also and add a `GROUP BY uid`, its not picking up the last entry.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select uid, itemDescription, date
from SEARCH s
where s.date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-30' and
      s.date = (select max(s2.date)
                from search s2
                where s2.uid = s.uid and
                      s2.date = s.date
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `search(uid, date)`.

You can also try window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by uid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from search s
      where .date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-30' 
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It times out when I try to run this.