# What is the best way to split this string value up?

Tags: php, regex, datetime, explode

The string value will be something like `P0DT0H4M13S`

```
P can be ignored.
0D is the DAY
0H is the HOUR
4M is the MINUTE
13S is the SECOND
```

It would be nice to do something like 4:13.

If there is a day then 1 DAY 4:13

HOUR AND DAY can be 1 DAY 4:4:13

I was trying to explode it, but that just seems silly, is there a regex that can handle this split?

THANKS!

Comment: Where are you having issues? There are many ways this could be done with regex.

Comment: ` \d+` is a suitable placeholder for numbers, Else [DateInterval::createFromDateString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [this question you asked earlier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60932823/1415724) Seeing it's date-related. And what's the source of your data?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no. It's a different problem. That didn't have anything to do with date.

Comment: @soldfor Ah ok thanks, I had to ask. Sometimes it happens that questions not far apart from themselves have relation that could have offered a different method, had it been database related. Make pretend like I didn't say anything *lol!* - P.s.: *Wash you hands, pass it on!* ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a PHP [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) string, and should be processed using that class. For example:

```
$str = 'P0DT0H4M13S';

$interval = new DateInterval($str);
$output = '';
if ($interval->d) {
    $output = $interval->format('%d DAY ');
}
$output .= $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
00:04:13
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XE8fO)

Obviously the code can be modified to skip the hour in the same way as the day if desired.

Comment: Thanks Nick!! Saved me some time and lines of code. Now to run it through a Ajax counter. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex

```
^.(?:([1-9]*)|0)DT(\d+)H(\d+)M(\d+)S\b
```

which has four capture groups, correspond to the day (`$1`), hour, minute and second. If capture group 1 matches (the day is greater than zero), your desired string is (pseudo-code)

```
$1 DAY $2:$3:4$
```

If the day is zero, the string is

```
$2:$3:4$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwvOsH/2/)

The PRCE regex engine performs the following operations:

```
^           # match beginning of line
.           # match 1 char 
(?:         # begin non-cap grp
  ([1-9]*)  # match '0'-'9' in capture group 1
  |         # or
  0         # match '0'
)           # end non-cap grp
DT          # match string 
(\d+)H      # match 1+ digits in cap grp 2, then 'H'
(\d+)M      # match 1+ digits in cap grp 3, then 'M'
(\d+)S      # match 1+ digits in cap grp 4, then 'S'
\b          # match word break
```